# Are the Transitive Dependencies for Maven Artifacts with Classifiers Shared?

Tags: maven, gradle, pom.xml

It appears that all examples "out in the wild" of multiple artifacts being defined in the same project via classifiers share the same POM file.

Does this imply they all must have the same dependencies?

I could see cases where one would like to encode platform/architecture/jvm  versions in classifiers, which might imply different dependencies. Is there an example of this someplace?

**Addon:** I've found some discussion about including a "flattened" no-dependencies variant as an artifact with classifiers, but not very helpful discussion.

Comment: Yes they share the same pom file and in result also the same dependencies. If you need different platfrom/architecture you should make different modules for that. The relationship to jvm options i dont understand. What kind of JVM options are we talking about?

Comment: I meant jvm versions. If you build something for jdk1.5, the dependencies better match... I suppose that's stretching the classifier concept.

Comment: So for example building with JDK 6, JDK 7, JDK 8  something like this? If so than a classifier does not make sense. Apart from things like a multi versions jar's of JDK 9 ...As i mentioned before making different modules and using things like toolchains for that...

Comment: That's fine... I've chosen a different tack... My goal was to figure out a way to map gradle projects which can produce many artifacts to maven poms, which usually only describe one, except for classifiers.